# Campo String guarda como entero php objetos y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, poo

Tengo un `update` que se realiza de la siguiente manera.

```
 public function update_donante($tabla,$caso,$link,$campo,$tipodonante){

            $this->tabla=$tabla;
            $this->caso=$caso;
            $this->con=$link;
            $this->campo=$campo;
            $this->tipodonante=$tipodonante;

$this->sqll= "UPDATE ".$this->tabla." SET ".$this->campo."='".$this->tipodonante."' WHERE idCaso="."'".$this->caso."'";
            //die($this->sqll);
            $this->resull=mysql_query($this->sqll,$this->con);

}
```

esto se envía con una función `ajax`, y retorno con un `die();` para sacar la `query` por pantalla y ver lo que sale.

la `query` queda de la siguiente manera

> UPDATE patient_data SET tipo_donante='Donor' WHERE idCaso='159'

Esta bien escrita pero cuando la genero directamente por el `mysql` esta bien actualiza el campo, pero cuando lo hago desde el código me actualiza el campo a 1.

El campo esta en `nvarchar 200` que es mas de lo que necesito y las variables están correctas.

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `SHOW CREATE TABLE patient_data;`?

Answer (score 0):

Vale y me di cuenta lo que pasaba el proceso estaba correcto pero antes de ello tenia un condicional

switch ($metodo) {
        case 'update':

```
        if($tipodonante!=""){
            $consultas->update($tabla,$id_caso,$link,$campo,$valor);

            $campo="tipo_donante";

            $consultas->update_donante($tabla,$id_caso,$link,$campo,$tipodonante);

        }else{
            $consultas->update($tabla,$id_caso,$link,$campo,$valor);
        }
        break;
```

Entonces no lo tenia cerrado  correctamente,¿ que pasaba ?  al  salir me faltaba el else (para ver si se cumplia o no), que pasaba y sobreescribia con el valor de un campo numérico ya que renombraba el campo.